# Share HttpClient between services

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, service, httpclient, blazor

I am working on a Blazor project, and to make the question I have easier to understand, we can say that I am using two different services that handles the Authentication part. Those are registered in the configureservices startup method together with a named httpclient.

```
services.AddHttpClient("XBOWServicesApi", c =>
{
c.BaseAddress = new Uri(XBOWServicesApi);
});

services.AddSingleton<IService1, Service1>();
services.AddSingleton<IService2, Service2>();
```

Service 1: Wraps all functionality available in a REST Api. It uses an http client which is set in the constructor via an instanciated httpclientfactory. This needs to be set with a baseurl and an Auth-header to work.

```
public Service1(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
this.httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("XBOWServicesApi");
}
```

Service 2: Handles the login/logout functionality using a custom AuthenticationStateProvider. It has its own httpclient, so that I can set the Auth Header for the http client. The constructor works in the same way as for Service 1.

```
public Service2(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
this.httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("XBOWServicesApi");
}
```

The reason for this build up is of course that I like to share the same http client, so when it is set in the login/logout methods, service 1 will have the correct auth header when communicating with the api.

However, the client factory provides a new instance everytime, so this will never work.

Any ideas how to handle this?

/Henrik

Answer (score 1):

You can use `named client`:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("github", c =>
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    // Github API versioning
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    // Github requires a user-agent
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
});
```

Afterwards, just call `CreateClient` method with corresponding `name` parameter.

```cs
var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("github");
```

Each time `CreateClient` is called:

- A new instance of HttpClient is created.
- The configuration action is
  called.

You can find more details in Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

When I read through the [Microsoft IHttpClientFactory docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests#httpclient-lifetimes):

> Each time you get an HttpClient object from the IHttpClientFactory, a
> new instance is returned. But each HttpClient uses an
> HttpMessageHandler that's pooled and reused by the IHttpClientFactory
> to reduce resource consumption, as long as the HttpMessageHandler's
> lifetime hasn't expired.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: but will this mean that if I set the Authorization header in one function, and later on a new httpclient is created in another function, will the auth header still be there?

Answer (score 0):

> You can share scoped services between transient HttpClients by using HttpMessageHandlers.

`IHttpClient.CreateClient` returns a new instance every time, but you can register a `HttpMessageHandler` as shown below:

```
services.AddScoped<HandlerData>();
services.AddTransient<HeaderHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient("XBOWServicesApi", c =>
{
c.BaseAddress = new Uri(XBOWServicesApi);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<HeaderHandler>();
```

**HeaderHandler Class:**

```
public class HeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    public HeaderHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
    {
        var Data= this.httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<HandlerData>();
        request.Headers.Add(Data.HeaderName, Data.HeaderValue);
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**HandlerData Class:**

```
public class HandlerData
{
    public string HeaderName { get; set; }
    public string HeaderValue { get; set; }
}
```

**ServicesCode:**

```
public Service1(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory, HandlerData data)
{
    data.HeaderName = "Header1";
    data.HeaderValue = "Value";
    this.httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("XBOWServicesApi");
}
public Service2(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
{
    //This will contain the same headers as Service1 as HandlerData is Scoped Service
    this.httpClient = clientFactory.CreateClient("XBOWServicesApi");
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use new `IHttpMessageHandlerFactory` if you need to create handlers that live in the same DI scope as you request:

Reference: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/issues/166